# Distance metrics in "high" dimensions

Tags: distance-functions, high-dimensional

Thanks in advance: this is a very nice site.

This question has been made more specific in response to a comment.

original question -----------------

Reading the various sources concerning distance metrics, one sees phrases such as "it depends on your data"; implying that choosing/defining the best metric is application specific, further implying the necessity of experimentation.

Does anyone out there know of a single source that collects usable definitions of the various choices?

Or can someone just LIST all the things I should research? (I'm working on such a list, but as a non-expert, it's difficult to know that one has found all the basic options without accidentally including a number of methods that are actually very closely related, and, it's hard to know from single articles if some group of methods has been, in some sense, superseded by a newer technique. )

Or are the basic choices likely to be part of a textbook on some subject?

As a non-expert, it is a daunting task to perform this literature search when most current articles are, say, the fifth article in a series on one detail of a variant of k-clustering. What I need are side-by-side implementable descriptions of the basic choices, in terms abstracted from the various universes (like "DNA").

new info--------------------

More specifically: I am working with a vector space of ~500 dimensions, in which all points have non-zero values on less than 20 dimensions, and in which all the values are normalized.  Similarity of vectors is the goal question, and an assumption is that a distance function defines similarity.

The dimensions represent conceptual aspects of linguistic meaning, and points are, among other things, unambiguous, single-meaning words (unlike many real words). For points representing actual words it is possible to make an empirical judgement about the similarity of words, and to use this judgement to evaluate distance metrics. However, many points are not words and so can't be used to evaluate a distance metric.

Some a priori clustering is known, as for instance when, in recursive definitions, the definition of "apple" includes the word "fruit". Also, we know of hundreds of languages - consequently the probability that English is the best language for natural-language research is small - and it is quite obvious that for my work an inflected language is better, so I am using Latin. The regularities in the meaning of Latin inflections provides another set of a priori clusters. I have other ways of knowing about these sorts of similarities, and I primarily need a distance metric for situations in which these known clusters are not involved.

Comment: I think that your question should be more specific. What specific problem is it that you are trying to solve? Distance metrics can depend on data in the sense that it matters whether your data is multivariate, univariate, time-dependent, etc. Whether one metric is preferable over another also depends on what your goal is in doing analysis. Distance metrics is a broad topic. Just about everything in statistics can be whittled to distance metric problems.